# Create a vector x from a chi-squared distribution

Tags: r

Create a vector x which will contain 1000 realisations from a χ^2
(5) distribution (χ^2(5) denotes a chi-squared distribution with 5 degrees of freedom). Then give the
commands to produce:

(i) a vector containing the 2nd, 50th and 800th elements,

(ii) a vector containing the first 250 elements,

(iii) a vector containing all elements except those from the 100th to the 900th
,

(iv) a vector containing all values larger than 1.5,

(v) a vector containing all values that are either > 6 or < 4,

(vi) a vector containing the first, second and third quartile,

(vii) a random sample of size 500 from the elements of x without replacement.

So, i'm not sure whether my answers are correct but this is my attempt:

```
x=(1:1000),
y=dchisq(x, df=5),

y[c(2,50,800)] #i)

y[1:250] #ii)

y[-c(100:900)] #iii)

y[c(1,5:1000)] #iv)

y[-c(4:6)] #v)

y[-c(750:1000)] #vi)

sample(x,500,replace=FALSE) #vii)
```

Are these right?

Comment: `dchisq` is bad---that's the density function. `rchisq` is used for random draws. After that, your look good for i-iii and vii, but the rest do not look good. I'd recommend experimenting with a small vector (say, 20 realizations from the distribution) and working it out based on that. You'll need to use comparisons like `<` and `>` and the `quantile` function.

Comment: `dchisq` returns the pdf and not a random number. See `?rchisq` instead.Your answer to (iv) is not correct, read on [logical indexing](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/logical-indexing.html) instead.Finally, you might be interested in the `?quantile` function.

Comment: @Gregor 
Right, so 
y[(y>1.5)] #iv)

y[(y>6) | (y<4)] #v)

quantile(x,probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) #vi)

would this be correct

Comment: You shouldn't need me to tell you. Run it on an example small enough that you can tell yourself whether it's correct or not.

Comment: yep, just checked and it works, thanks!